# How to process a JSON with multiple array s

Tags: android, json

The is my JSON string .

```
    { 
      "server_response":
        { 
             "source_response" : 
                       [
                        {"stoppage_name":"sealdah","bus_no":"43@230@234/1@30_A"}
                       ] ,
             "destination_response" :                 
                      [
                        {"stoppage_name":"howrah","bus_no":"43@234/1@30_A"}
                      ]
          }
 }
```

I think there would be a '[' after "server_response" , but not sure . 
I am trying to retrieve the data but the code is not working .

```
 try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            int count=0 ;
            String stoppage,busno;
            while(count<1)
            {
                JSONArray JA = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
                JSONObject JO = JA.getJSONObject(count);

                stoppage = JO.getString("stoppage_name");
                busno = JO.getString("bus_no");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stoppage ="+ stoppage+" Bus no =" +busno, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                count ++;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Where I am making wrong . I am new to JSON and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
 jsonServerObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("server_response");
 jsonSourceArray = jsonServerObject.getJSONArray("source_response");
 jsonDestinationArray =     jsonServerObject.getJSONArray("destination_response");
     //Iterate your 2 arrays`

Answer (score 0):

`server_response` is not a `JSONArray`, it's a `JSONObject`. Because array have numeric key, not string.

Comment: Okay. So should I use '[' ?

Comment: If you use `[]`, you can't make `"source_response" :` in it.

Answer (score 0):

i have already answer this type of question .. what you have to do .. use multiple for loop to getting value inside array under array.

this is srceen shots 
[image]

```
            JSONArray objJson = new JSONArray(strJSONData);



                 System.out.println("AppUserLogin:"+objJson);
                // Parsing json


                if(arrJson.length()>0)
                {
                for (int i = 0; i < objJson.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject objprod = arrJson.getJSONObject(i);

                        HashMap<String, String> MaplistTemp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        MaplistTemp.put("replyCode",
                                objprod.getString("replyCode"));

                        MaplistTemp.put("replyCode",
                                objprod.getString("replyCode"));

                        JSONArray objproduct_var = new JSONArray(objprod.getString("LearningStandards"));

                        if ((objproduct_var.length()) > 0) {
                            for (int k = 0; k < objproduct_var.length(); k++) {
                                JSONObject objprodvar = objproduct_var
                                        .getJSONObject(k);



                                    MaplistTemp
                                            .put("1",
                                                    objprodvar
                                                            .getString("1"));
                                    MaplistTemp
                                            .put("2",
                                                    objprodvar
                                                            .getString("2"));
                                    MaplistTemp
                                            .put("3",
                                                    objprodvar
                                                            .getString("3"));
                                    MaplistTemp
                                    .put("4",
                                            objprodvar
                                                    .getString("4"));

                            }
                        }
                        // sub_categorys_details.add(sub_cat_det);

                medpostList.add(MaplistTemp);// adding to final hashmap
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , and **{} = object [] = array**

```
try{
jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
injsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("server_response");

jsonArray = injsonObject.getJSONArray("source_reponse");
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: jsonObject ,injsonObject ,jsonArray  all there are JSONObject ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
```

Here you are trying to access server_response as an array. It isn't an array. "server_response" is the key to the nested object:

```
{ 
     "source_response" : 
               [
                {"stoppage_name":"sealdah","bus_no":"43@230@234/1@30_A"}
               ] ,
     "destination_response" :                 
              [
                {"stoppage_name":"howrah","bus_no":"43@234/1@30_A"}
              ]
  }
```

See? Thats not an array, tis a JSON object with two keys, each of them have an array as value.

I'm not very familiar with android or java but in plain old javascript you could try something like:

```
var sourceResp = jsonObject.server_response.source_response;
```

or

```
var sourceResp = jsonObject["server_response"]["source_response"];
```

That will produce an array with one item in it.
I hope this can get you going.

Comment: Okay . I am trying this way .